# How do i display the ouput in the same PHP page

Tags: php, html

I have written a code and now i want to view the output of user selected radio button in the same php page?

How can i do it? Here is my code

```
<html>
<div>
<form>
<input type='submit'  name='radiotest' value='1crn' /> </div>  
<input type='submit'  name='radiotest' value='1FFZ' /> </div>  
</form>
</div>
<div>
<head>
<script src="jmol/Jmol.js"></script> 
</head>
<script>
jmolInitialize("jmol");
</script>
<script>
jmolSetAppletColor("gray");
jmolApplet(450, "load <?php echo "/jmol/".$_REQUEST['radiotest'].".pdb"; ?>; select      all; cartoon on; wireframe off; spacefill off; color chain; ");
</script> 
</div>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Could you please elaborate more on what you mean by "i want to view the output of user selected radio button in the same php page". Do you mean you want to change the "jmolApplet"-part without reloading the page?

Comment: yes!! @vstm  sorry for making it unclear... and thanks for understanding it

Comment: why are you doing this with `PHP`, you can do this just by using `Jquery` OR `JavaScript`

Comment: I am more comfortable working with php than java. I tried doing with java but it dint workout for me. Is there anyway to bring the output in the same php page?

Comment: Check out this sample page: http://jmol.sourceforge.net/demo/atoms/ - with the `jmolRadio` function you can create a radio button which executes some jmol-commands. I guess you could create the radio button like that: `jmolRadio("load /jmol/1FFZ.pdb", "Show 1FFZ");`.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be done using PHP (javascript would be a better candidate), but to answer the question:

Make the form so it has an action and method attributes. Action will be the current page (you don't need to specify this attribute if it's the same page) and method will be GET or POST.

Something like this:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
```

Now, when you click the button, the form gets submitted and the page reloads but the URL is different:

```
http://site.com/page.php?radiotest=1crn
```

You can now check to see if the `$_GET['radiotest']` is set using `isset()` function. If it is set, do whatever you want it to do.

`isset($_GET['radiotest'])` - tells you if `radiotest=something` is in the URL

`$_GET['radiotest']` - gives you the value of "something" from `radiotest=something` in the URL.

Because PHP is a server-side language, all code gets executed on the server. By the time the page gets sent to the browser, it has already executed and no further computations can be made. If you must have a PHP solution, the request must be sent to the server, the page must reload.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one of the way to display the output in the same page...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name='test' method='GET' action="">
<input type='radio'  name='radiotest' value='1crn' />1crn
<input type='radio'  name='radiotest' value='1FFZ' />1FFz
<input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit' />
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_GET("submit")))
{
    echo $_GET["radiotest"];
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```